# Distrust of the Symantec PKI in Chrome Canary - No Visual Warning

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to verify some sites to get ready for the chrome 66 official release.

Reading through the bulletin https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html it suggests chrome canary would display the page error.

However when I check a known affected site, I only receive the console warning. Is there a flag I need to turn on?

Chrome version: Version 67.0.3364.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

The console warning would be sufficient in most cases, but I need to verify, permanent HTTPS redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is going to distrust Symantec in 2 steps

1. In Chrome 66 - SSL/TLS certificate from Symantec that was issued
   before June 1, 2016, it will stop functioning in Chrome 66
2. In Chrome 70 - All remaining Symantec SSL/TLS certificates will stop
   working. This cannery is not yet released, planed to release in July 20, 2018

So your certificate may be in the second category. That's why you get only the warning message in console.